# How to use DropDownPreference to change theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-settings

I want to use a `DropDownPreference` for my settings page but despite looking all over the internet, there doesn't seem to be any decent tutorial on how to do this. Does anyone know what should go in the `onPreferenceChange` method? I previously used a `RadioButton` but now want to use a `DropDownPreference` for easier implementation and maintenance.

**Activity**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentSettings.PreferenceXchangeListener {
    private var mCurrentValue: Boolean = false // False is the default value

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        mCurrentValue = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("preference_dark", false)

        if (mCurrentValue) {
            setTheme(R.style.MyDarkSettingsTheme)
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.MyLightSettingsTheme)
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)


        val viewllSettingsContainer = settings_container
        val root = viewllSettingsContainer.rootView


        if (mCurrentValue) {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
        } else {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }

        val settingsFragment = FragmentSettings()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_container, settingsFragment)
            .commit()
    }


    override fun onXchange(value:Boolean) {
        when {
            mCurrentValue != value -> {
                mCurrentValue = value
                recreate()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                val intent = parentActivityIntent
                intent?.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                onBackPressed()
                true
            }

            else ->
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener,
    Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating it. There is no need to involve the fragment in listening to changes to a preference it won't be handling and passing that back to the activity. You can register a preference change listener for all preferences in your Activity and respond accordingly there.

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        //...
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        //...
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(_: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
        when (key){
            "preference_dark" -> recreate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: `Unresolved reference: mSharedPreferences` in the `onDestroy` method

Comment: I thought you already had a reference because of the name in your own class. Having an `m` at the start of a variable name is a Java convention called Hungarian notation that indicates it is a member variable (aka field). In the case of Kotlin that would correspond with a class parameter. You can just use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` to get a reference again in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: How do I add preference from a resource? i.e. `R.xml.app_preferences`? Does this go in the activity or do I need to create a fragment for this?

Comment: Aren't you already doing that in your Fragment? Yes, you must do it with a Fragment. The old way of doing it with a PreferenceActivity is deprecated in favor of the support/androidx library, which only supports preferences from a PreferenceFragment.

Comment: You can basically delete everything below the fourth line of code you showed for your fragment, except for closing braces.

Comment: The `onSharedPreferenceChanged` function isn't working for some reason and doesn't get called at all.